# Browser caching for captive portal

Tags: python, html, caching

I'm having a problem with a custom captive portal implemented with iptables and some python authentication scripts.

When a user makes an initial connection to the network and attempts to access a website for the first time (e.g. `http://www.google.com`) they are redirected to the portal for authentication as is required.

The problem occurs after authentication. If a user trys to visit the website that initially triggered their "capture" (in this example, Google) they are redirected back to the portal once again. An attempt to visit any other website except Google will work fine. In addition, repeatedly clicking on a Google link will eventually resolve the loop and the user can navigate to Google as desired...

Is this a problem with browser caching? I have the following code in the HEAD of my HTML pages:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: You should send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header instead. What does your Python code look like?